# Thermal overload trip in chips

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture

I have read that the thermal design power (TDP) is an important metric while considering energy and power trade off related to microcontrollers. It is said that TDP determines the cooling required and failure to meet that values results in increase of junction temperature of the processor. A possible solution is either reduce the clock frequency or activate a thermal overload trip. I wanted to know what exactly is this thermal overload trip and how is it implemented in the processors?

Comment: It may well vary from CPU to CPU, have you tried reading any CPU datasheets?

Comment: No, I haven't read any cpu datasheet. Could I get a reference of any which would also cover answer to my question

Answer (score -2):

Internal Diodes can measure voltage by negative temp coefficient (NTC) and thus convert to a temperature. Many chips have overtemp protection (OTP), such as Smart switches and regulators.

Power dissipation is computed by Ohm's Law for static loads and switched charges with driver ESR losses for CMOS that vary with V and f and given in datsheets near the end of xxx pages.

Thermal design is spec'd with thermal resistance **Rjc**, junction to case and junction to ambient **Rja** by ['C/W] then heatink or force air cooling is like Ohm's law for thermal resistance. Heatsinks and interface thermal grease are then added in series, **Rja** (jcn to ambient) with convection air.  Forced air can improve resistance from 10% to a few % proprotional to surface velocity.

An Intel CPU has a very low **Rjc** and then a forced air heatsink needs **Rca** of <0.1 to 0.2'C/W to keep cool, depending on budget $ and power [W] so that the **sum of all thermal R's *Pd = temp rise above ambient.**

Comment: Power is calculated by [Joule's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating) (or Joule-Lenz law) - not Ohm's law.

Comment: We once had to do it with Gauss' Law. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical101.com%2Fwpimages%2Fohms-law-peir-symbol.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical101.com%2Fohms-law.html&docid=NCQisqr11UhoKM&tbnid=bH9nbzQ51F7qdM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjdnPbQrqbaAhXq5oMKHf0cAR4QMwj2ASgOMA4..i&w=253&h=241&client=firefox-b-ab&bih=725&biw=1536&q=ohm%27s%20law&ved=0ahUKEwjdnPbQrqbaAhXq5oMKHf0cAR4QMwj2ASgOMA4&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: You seem like a nice guy, but could you please stop sprinkling out double spaces and spaces before comma? Irks me to the bone.

Comment: typing on an iPod is not the easiest especially if lying under a palm tree on the beach. May I suggest anger management training